# Problemas con el navbar y el contenido de la pagina

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Paso a comentar mi problema:

Tengo un `navbar` lateral y el contenido de la pagina se me superpone arriba del `navbar` cuando lo quiero mover:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el Código:

```
 </head>

    <body> 

  <!-- Sidenav -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-vertical fixed-left navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white" id="sidenav-main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Toggler -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidenav-collapse-main" aria-controls="sidenav-main" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- Brand -->
      <a class="navbar-brand pt--0" href="../Menu/verEntradas.aspx">
        <img src="../assets/img/brand/logoCrowe.png" class="navbar-brand-img" alt="...">
      </a>

         <!-- User -->
      <ul class="nav align-items-center d-md-none">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link nav-link-icon" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="ni ni-bell-55"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-arrow dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbar-default_dropdown_1">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <div class="media align-items-center">
              <span class="avatar avatar-sm rounded-circle">
                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="./assets/img/theme/team-1-800x800.jpg">
              </span>
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-arrow dropdown-menu-right">
            <div class=" dropdown-header noti-title">
              <h6 class="text-overflow m-0">Welcome!</h6>
            </div>
            <a href="./examples/profile.html" class="dropdown-item">
              <i class="ni ni-single-02"></i>
              <span>My profile</span>
            </a>
            <a href="./examples/profile.html" class="dropdown-item">
              <i class="ni ni-settings-gear-65"></i>
              <span>Settings</span>
            </a>
            <a href="./examples/profile.html" class="dropdown-item">
              <i class="ni ni-calendar-grid-58"></i>
              <span>Activity</span>
            </a>
            <a href="./examples/profile.html" class="dropdown-item">
              <i class="ni ni-support-16"></i>
              <span>Support</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a href="#!" class="dropdown-item">
              <i class="ni ni-user-run"></i>
              <span>Logout</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>


          <!-- Collapse -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="sidenav-collapse-main">
        <!-- Collapse header -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse-header d-md-none">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 collapse-brand">
              <a href="../index.html">
                <img src="../assets/img/brand/blue.png">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 collapse-close">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidenav-collapse-main" aria-controls="sidenav-main" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle sidenav">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


            <!-- Navigation -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../Menu/verEntradas.aspx">
              <i class="ni ni-tv-2 text-primary"></i> Dashboard
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../Menu/TiposDeCarga.aspx">
              <i class="ni ni-planet text-blue"></i> Tipos de cargas
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../Menu/verCuentas.aspx">
              <i class="ni ni-book-bookmark text-orange"></i> Cuentas
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../Menu/verUsuarios.aspx">
              <i class="ni ni-single-02 text-yellow"></i> Usuarios
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../PruebasAutoTabla1/botonesPruebas.aspx">
              <i class="ni ni-bullet-list-67 text-red"></i> Pruebas automaticas
            </a>
          </li>          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">
                <form onclick="btnSalir_Click">
                    <i class="ni ni-button-power text-info"></i> Salir
                </form>              
            </a>
          </li>



        </ul>
        <!-- Divider -->
        <hr class="my-3">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <h6 class="navbar-heading text-muted">Documentacion</h6>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav mb-md-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <i class="ni ni-spaceship"></i> Primeros pasos
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <i class="ni ni-palette"></i> Guia completa
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <i class="ni ni-ui-04"></i> Componentes
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


        <div class="main-content">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-14">                    
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                          <asp:GridView ID="grDatos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" onrowcommand="grDatos_RowCommand"  CssClass="table table-hover align-items-center table-dark table-flush">
                <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Numero Transaccion" DataField="TransaccionId" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha de creacion" DataField="FechaCreacion" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cantida de Cuentas Imputadas" DataField="CantidadCuentas" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total Debito" DataField="debito" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total Credito" DataField="credito" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cantidad Usuarios Imputadas" DataField="CantidaUsuarios" />                        
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cantidad de fechas de registracion Imputadas" DataField="CantidadFechas" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ultima fecha de registro" DataField="FechaRegistracion" />
                        <asp:ButtonField Text="Detalles" CommandName="Detalles" />
                </Columns>
                 <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />                 
                 <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 </asp:GridView>   
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

             <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                <asp:GridView ID="grDatosDescargar" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Transaccion id" DataField="TransaccionId" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha Registracion" DataField="fecha" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo Comprobante" DataField="codigo_comprobante" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo de cuentas" DataField="AccountCode" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cuenta descripcion" DataField="Description" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Monto Neto" DataField="NetAmount" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Creacion de cuenta" DataField="CreatedDate" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tipo de documento" DataField="DocumentType" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Usuario" DataField="nombreApellido_usuario" />                        
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Jornal descripcion" DataField="JournalDescription" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Linea descripcion" DataField="LineDescription" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Movimiento" DataField="Descripcion" />                        
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />                 
                 <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br />
    <br />

                <table align="right">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>Descargue todas las transacciones hechas hasta el momento: </h5>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Descargar a Excel" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" OnClick="btnExcel_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>


<!-- Argon Scripts -->
  <!-- Core -->
  <script src="../assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Optional JS -->
  <script src="../assets/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../assets/vendor/chart.js/dist/Chart.extension.js"></script>
  <!-- Argon JS -->
  <script src="../assets/js/argon.js?v=1.0.0"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

¿Alguna idea? o ¿decirme que puedo estar haciendo mal? Se lo agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Es preferible que solo compartas el codigo relevante para replicar el problema; tanto codigo lo hace dificil de manejar y puede confundir a las personas; ademas faltan cosas en tu codigo para poder replicarlo; no hay estilos, ni funciones por ende causa errores en consola